# Kernel methods on Categorical Data

Tags: categorical-data, kernel-trick

I have a basic understanding of kernel methods and the kernel-trick and the advantages of it, why it is preferred over conventional machine learning algorithms etc. However, I have some trouble using them.
The problems I face are as follows, 

1. can I use a kernel metric for (dissimilarity) calculation?

2. what steps need to be taken for using a kernel method (say, using the gaussian kernel) on a set of categorical (along with numerical) data. consider the following sample data
    
Age     State    Day
    
12      NJ       Tue 
    
24      NM       Wed
    
89      CA       Thu
    
.       .         .
   
 .       .         .

The question is do I need to explicitly encode the categorical values in order to use it on the gaussian kernel for similarity calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, the best one being using a kernel function that is tailored to your specific problem. This is also the least intuitive option, so I won't elaborate on that.

Usually, categorical data are encoded using so-called one-hot encoding. This means we introduce one binary feature for every category. For instance, assume we have 3 categories $A$, $B$ and $C$:
$$
A \rightarrow [1, 0 ,0],\quad B\rightarrow[0,1,0],\quad C\rightarrow[0,0,1]
$$
The crucial thing is that we must ensure that all pairwise distances are equal, otherwise the distance will be biased towards some pairs (unless, ofcourse, this is what you want). One-hot encoding is the simplest way to ensure that all pairwise distances between categories are equal.

Comment: Assuming that the pairwise similarity is equal (if we want it so ) can we use this as the input for a kernel method, once we use bitmap-indexing (or one-hot encoding as it is named)?

Comment: @damith219 yes, you can use the binary representation as input.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, by definition, kernel is some kind of similarity not dissimilarity.
2. Basically, kernel is a way to express your domain knowledge of the data. For discrete values, you'd better use a kernel that is suitable for the data. Always using Gaussian kernel no matter what data you have is a bad practice.

BTW, kernel methods themselves do not make much sense.

Comment: Statements like 'kernel methods do not make much sense' are not very useful without at least some justification. Given the vast amount of research being done on this particular topic, it's fair to say many experts disagree.

Comment: You are right. It is just a personal opinion.

Comment: Any measure of similarity can be turned into a measure of dissimilarity. E.g. by multiplying with $-1$.

Comment: I agree with Marc. The kernel trick, for example uses the kernel itself as an effective classification method without employing any other machine learning technique, if I am correct in understanding it.